# setting up cookies with jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-dialog

I am trying to make a dialog box on my site with following code. my HTML code having 3 images with link in dialog like this.

```
<div id="dialogoc" title="Click Your Flag">
    <a href="#"><img src="image path/> <h2>Saudi 

Arabia</h2> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="image path"/> <h2>Unites 

States</h2> </a>
<a href="#"><img src="image path"/> 

<h2>Pakistan</h2> </a>
</div>
```

and i am using the following function

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialogoc" ).dialog();
});
```

There is no button in this dialog box so I am confuse how to set cookies for this. 
Thanks

Comment: Assuming you're using jQueryUI dialog, check out their documentation on binding event handlers - you'll probably want to bind to the `open` or `close` event to set a cookie: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the click events of the links, set a cookie, close the box, and return false (so the link doesn't open)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no button on my dialog there is just 3 images with links, 
We can catch click event on button but cant on catch click on link..
AM I RIGHT, if not let me know how could I can do .
Thanks

Comment: $('a').click( function() { your_code_here; return false; } ); Important is the return false;